Unexpected Behavior with Firebase Realtime Database onDisconnect and cancel in Nested References
In my React app, I'm facing an issue with Firebase Realtime Database. I set up onDisconnect operations for two nested references. However, canceling the operation on testRef2 unexpectedly affects testRef1.
useEffect(() => {
  const testRef1 = ref(db, `rooms/${roomID}/players/${currentUid}`);
  const testRef2 = ref(db, `rooms/${roomID}/players/${currentUid}/isCreator`);

  onDisconnect(testRef1).remove();  
  onDisconnect(testRef2).set(true); 
  onDisconnect(testRef2).cancel();  
}, []);

Problem: I expect onDisconnect(testRef1).remove() to execute on tab close, but onDisconnect(testRef2).cancel() seems to cancel it. The Firebase docs say cancel() should only affect its location and children.
Observations:

Strangely, removing onDisconnect(testRef2).set(true) fixes the issue.
Removing onDisconnect(testRef2).cancel() makes everything work as expected: the player is removed first, and then testRef2 is created with isCreator set to true.

Questions:

Why does cancel() on testRef2 affect testRef1?
How can I ensure onDisconnect(testRef1).remove() works correctly?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
